# Accessing byte elements in "Memory"

Tags: java, jna

Iam trying to read a binary file to memory and pass the starting address of the memory block to a native function:

```
 Memory image = new Memory(length);
 int offset = 0;
 int numRead = 0;
  try
  {
    while (offset < image.size() && (numRead = in.read(image.getByteArray(0,(int)image.size()), offset, (int)image.size() - offset)) >= 0)
     {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < image.size())
    {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + fileFileName.getName());
    }
    in.close();
  }
  catch(Exception IOException)
  {
      System.out.println("\nError Occured in try block!!!");
  }
  byte imageByte = image.getByte(0);
```

The problem is that the value of imageByte is -60 instead of 127. I checked by taking a byte array(instead of Memory) and reading the file into it. But it too showed 127 for array[0]. What can be the problem here???

Comment: Please add your resolution as an answer and mark it as excepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i resolved the problem :D since getByteArray() returns a new byte array, the data was being copied to that new byte array and the memory region that i want to use remained uninitialised